# C# HttpClient; How to make safe async calls?

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, httpclient

I have a site that exercises a third party API.  This API will tell me the values of accounts for a user.  The API has become unresponsive, and this has highlighted a flaw in my code.  I am getting the exception "Thread was being aborted." in the try-catch trap around the call, and in EventViewer I can see the HttpException RequestTimedOut.

I am trying to use HttpClient, in a synchronous manner.  This works fine when the API is responsive, but it is coming apart now that the API is very slow to respond.

I have an overview page that tries to gather all the account values for all users.
There are 3 types of users (CLIENT, LIAISON, MEMBER).  The page makes three asynchronous Javascript calls for each type of account.  The fact that there are three calls made is (most probably) a red-herring, but I am declaring it to be safe.

The server takes each call, gets the users for each call.  So, for the CLIENT call, the system pulls up the all the CLIENT users, and serially steps through them.  It makes an HTTP request per CLIENT user to get the account value.

Each call has a new HttpClient object created for it, wrapped in a using statement.

I strongly suspect that IIS is spotting the idle thread and shutting it down, which is fair enough.

How can I make the API call so that I return the thread to the pool until I get a response?

```
    private static string getTotalAssets(string blockChainAddress, string identity)
    {
        var prefix = "getTotalAssets() - ";
        string msg = "";

        using (var handler = new HttpClientHandler { UseCookies = false, PreAuthenticate = true })
        using (var client = new HttpClient(handler))
        {
            // Timeout
            TimeSpan tsTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, _timeout);
            client.Timeout = tsTimeout;

            var message = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, _urlSettleAPIGetTotalAssets);

            // Accept Json
            message.Headers.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue(Constants.MIME_JSON));

            // Form the content to send
            string content = getTotalAssetsContent(blockChainAddress);

            // Add to the message
            message.Content = new StringContent(content);

            // Make API Call
            string sCallRef = "GET TOTAL ASSETS FOR [" + identity + "]";
            Tuple<HttpResponseMessage, string> result = MakeAPICall(client, message, content, sCallRef);
            if (result.Item1 == null)
                return result.Item2; // Error during call

            // Call returned
            HttpResponseMessage response = result.Item1;
            string responseString = result.Item2;

            if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                msg = "Response Status Code: " + response.StatusCode.ToString();
                logger.Debug(prefix + msg);
                return "Error [" + result.Item2 + "]; " + msg;
            }

            // Else, call returned 200-OK

            logger.Debug(prefix + "Response:\r\n" + responseString + "\r\n");

            return processGetTotalAssetsResponseString(responseString);

        } // end of using...
    }



    public static Tuple<HttpResponseMessage, string> MakeAPICall(HttpClient client, HttpRequestMessage message, string content, string callRef)
    {
        var prefix = "MakeAPICall() - ";
        string msg = "";

        HttpResponseMessage responseMessage;
        string responseString = "";
        try
        {
            responseMessage = client.SendAsync(message).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
            responseString = responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();

            return new Tuple<HttpResponseMessage, string>(responseMessage, responseString);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            msg = "Exception during call; \r\nBaseMessage:[" + ex.GetBaseException().Message + "]; \r\nMessage:[" + ex.Message + "]";
            logger.Warn(prefix + msg);

            return new Tuple<HttpResponseMessage, string>(null, msg);
        }

    } // end of MakeAPICall()
```

Comment: Why aren't you using `async/await`? Why `GetAwaiter()`? Given that all samples and documentation use `await` why did you use `GetAwaiter()` and `GetResult()`?

Comment: All samples use code like `var responseMessage= await client.SendAsync(message); var responseString = responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();` You could get rid of `MakeAPICall` and check the response directly. By using the tuple you simply force yourself to make another null check

Comment: If you use tasks in which you make synchronous calls you are 100% sure the thread will still be there until the action is completed, you can await the task then and handle the response on main thread.

Comment: @niklon, The API is not responding in a timely fashion, and the thread is being aborted by IIS.  When the API is responsive, the above code is fine.  The problem is that the thread is blocked, IIS detects it as inactive, and IIS kills the thread.  I could configure IIS to use longer tolerance, but I would rather code to deal with this situation.  Thx for the response.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, MakeAPICall is there because I call that function from many other functions, for lots of API endpoints.  The GetAwaiter() code lines were lifted from a StackOverflow question, which, naturally, I cannot now locate, but needless to say, I nicked it.  So; How would I re-write the above code to be properly asynchronous and relinquish the thread to the pool?

Comment: @SteveHibbert instead of blindly copying code, understand what it does. I already posted how you could rewrite this in a comment. A simple `var respMsg= await client.SendAsync(message);`. It's the calls to `GetResult()` , `Task.Result` or `Task.Wait()` that cause blocking. Instead of making an asynchronous call, you make a blocking one

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos.  I used the code at the level of understanding required at the time, and it worked, and it blocks.  Now I would like to improve the code, and make it truly asynchronous.  But, the call will return immediately if I do that, so I will need to restructure the functions.  I still have to provide a response to the calling web-page, so how do I hang up the call until the API call returns?

Comment: @SteveHIbbert no it *won't* return immediately. That's not how asynchronous calls and `await` work at all. `await` ensures that the rest of the code won't run until the asynchronous method returns. The original thread is released and available for other uses. Once the method returns, the rest of the code will run on the same synchronization context. In desktop applications, it means that the UI thread will be used. In web applications, it means that another threadpool thread will be used, set up with the correct HttpContext and execution will continue

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Ah! That's what I didn't get, I thought the call would complete.  My experience of async up to now has been that you get an immediate response and have to store a context yourself.  Would you like to create an answer that I could then accept?  I would greatly appreciate the code that I should use in the try-catch part of MakeAPICall, instead of the blocking calls.